# method overriding doesnt work as expected

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

*sorry if the title isnt very good, i couldnt think of anything else*

ive got this program:

```
class Animal
{
    private:
        int legs;
        string sound;
    protected:
        Animal(int l, string s) : legs(l), sound(s) {}
    public:
        Animal() {}
        string getClass()
        {
            return "Animal";
        }
        void printInfo()
        {
            cout <<"This is a(n) "<<getClass()<<". It has "<<getLegs()<<" legs and makes the sound: "<<getSound()<<"\n";
        }
        int getLegs()
        {
            return legs;
        }
        string getSound()
        {
            return sound;
        }
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
    public:
        Dog() : Animal(4,"bark")
        {
        }
        string getClass()
        {
            return "dog";
        }
};

int main()
{
    Animal a;
    Dog d;
    a.printInfo();
    d.printInfo();

    a=d;
    a.printInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

compiling and running results in this:

> This is a(n) Animal. It has 2002819627 legs and makes the sound:
>
> This is a(n) Animal. It has 4 legs and makes the sound: bark
>
> This is a(n) Animal. It has 4 legs and makes the sound: bark

why is it that i get "animal" as the class and not dog when i call `printInfo()` on `d`? (but still get the legs and sound correct somehow) i mean, why `Dog`'s `getClass` wont work when used on `printInfo()`; am i doing something wrong?

Comment: im just a stupid fish pls dont be harsh

Comment: Try adding `override` to the function that is expected to override the underlying method. Than follow the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason that you're getting the current num of legs but not the animel name it because how constructor works,
when you create Dog class you calling the base class constructor with the "right" num of legs and

`Dog() : Animal(4,"bark")`

but when you calling printInfo Dog is looking for this function but cant find it so it going to its base class and at the base class the class is "Animel".
you need to change the base class getInfo ginather to

```
virtual string getClass()
{
    return "Animal";
}
```

and this will resolve you problome

Answer (score 1):

There are two points:

1. Use `virtual` methods, so `getClass` for `Animal()` instance would return *"Animal"* and `getClass()` for `Dog` instance would return *"dog"*.
2. You have used default constructor for `a`, so `legs` contains some garbage value, you need to initialize it or remove default constructor.

```
class Animal
{
    private:
        int legs = DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_LEGS;
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        string sound = "DEFAULT_SOUND";
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    protected:
        Animal(int l, string s) : legs(l), sound(s) {}
    public:
        Animal() {}
        virtual string getClass()
//      ^^^^^^^
        {
            return "Animal";
        }
        void printInfo()
        {
            cout <<"This is a(n) "<<getClass()<<". It has "<<getLegs()<<" legs and makes the sound: "<<getSound()<<"\n";
        }
        int getLegs()
        {
            return legs;
        }
        string getSound()
        {
            return sound;
        }
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
    public:
        Dog() : Animal(4,"bark")
        {
        }
        string getClass() override
//                        ^^^^^^^^
        {
            return "dog";
        }
};

int main()
{
    Animal a;
    Dog d;
    a.printInfo();
    d.printInfo();

    a=d;
    a.printInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, might be a dumb question but i tried this earlier but without adding the `override` and it still worked, so is it necessary? (in this context at least)

Comment: @impatientsalmon It is not necessary, `override` is for just for checking if method is virtual. If you made a typo and wrote `string getClas()` for example `override` will help you to see this.